# Any way to find number of days in month using Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Instead of calculating the month and leap year to do this calculation. Is there any way to check using some Apple Internal APIs to do so?

I found that the Java have something like this:

```
calendar.getActualMaximum(calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```

Is there any similar thing for Objective C? thz u.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use `NSCalendar` and its `rangeOfUnit:inUnit:forDate` method. For example, to get the number of days in the current month:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSRange range = [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit inUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit forDate:[NSDate date]];
NSUInteger numberOfDaysInMonth = range.length;
```

Comment: Tested for February: `rng.length` is 29 on leap years and 28 on non-leap years (as expected but it doesn't hurt to check)

Comment: Just for information `NSDayCalendarUnit` and `NSMonthCalendarUnit` are `NSCalendarUnitDay` and `NSCalendarUnitMonth` in **iOS 8** and above.